# How to remove the keyboard from a Lenovo T400?

Tags: keyboard, thinkpad

I am trying to take off the keyboard of a Lenovo Thinkpad T400. I have seen several [YouTube tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=lenovo+thinkpad+t400+keyboard&oq=lenovo+thinkpad+t400+keyboard), an [official video by Lenovo](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/product-and-parts/detail.page?&LegacyDocID=MIGR-72540) and followed this [tutorial](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/product-and-parts/detail.page?&LegacyDocID=MIGR-71485). I already removed all screws not only the marked ones.

However the keyboard does **not** lift up on the **right side**. It feels as if there is a screw but it is not. Could be that the keyboard has melted with some other component? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In response to your edit...pull harder or try prying it up to see if you can localize the spot where it appears to be stuck?  There shouldn't be anything for it to catch on and I seriously doubt something's *melted*.

Comment: I fail to see how this is too localized compared to other model-specific questions, of which we have a ton.  Was there a policy change I missed?

Comment: Yeah, this question will apply to many ThinkPads.

Comment: Question reopened, this is not really how "too localized" should be interpreted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These do come off as advertised - either you missed a screw (should be five total) or it's just stuck to something.  I'm not really sure how it would be stuck, though...the newer ones don't require removing the palm rest so they can hang on that lip but this should be wide open.

Comment: He needs to try pushing it upwards (ie. towards the base of the screen). It clicks in under the bottom edge (palmrest).

Comment: @paradroid - That is true on newer systems, but not on the T400.  You have to remove the palmrest entirely on these first.  (The instructions do indicate that)

Comment: That's surprising, as that is how the keyboard fitted on my X200s, which is the same generation as the T400.

Comment: @paradroid - "s" SKUs were a bit different, as that was the first batch of them.  The T400s also had that style keyboard, and existed alongside the T400.  It wasn't adopted line-wide until the -10 series.

Comment: Finally, I managed to lift the keyboard with a help of a friend. There is actually a **very sticky gum** under the keyboard which I had to **pull of very hard**. It might be that it melted before because of **too much heat** and therefore became more sticky then normal. Thanks again for everyone's posts.